# About ID in route configuration of Spring Cloud Gateway

Tags: java, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

In Spring Cloud Gateway, in route configuration we can specify the id

```
@Bean
public RouteLocator customRouteLocator(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
        return builder.routes()
            .route(r -> r.path("/country/**")
                .uri("lb://COUNTRY-SERVICE/")
                //.id("<stringvalue>")
                )
            .route(r -> r.path("/**")
                    .uri("https://someothersite.com"))
            .build();
    }
```

What is .id("stringvalue") represent? Does the stringvalue we give can be any value? What is its significance?

Comment: It's useful in recognizing it when debugging and viewing routes in actuator

Comment: Thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 0):

Just to mention that the new way of writing down the id on the RouteLocatorBuilder is

````
@Bean
public RouteLocator customRouteLocator(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
        return builder.routes()
            .route("id", r -> r.path("/country/**")
                .uri("lb://COUNTRY-SERVICE/"))
            .route(r -> r.path("/**")
                    .uri("https://someothersite.com"))
            .build();
    }
```
````